# Batch FIle Properties

Tags: file, batch-file, properties

I need some help, I have a program that I made when you open it, it will launch another program, but here is the problem.
I would like to make a properties file so you can have the option to launch it with a dialog box that comes up and says "Would you like to launch this program?" Yes or No, but I also want to have the option to choose not to have it there, would it be possible to make a sort of properties file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to make a pop-up you will need to use a programming language (like `vbscript` or `C#`)but for the rest I can help you in console.

#### Launcher.bat

```
@echo off
if "%1"=="" choice /m "Continue? "
if errorlevel 1 Exit
if "%1"=="/y" choice /m "Continue? "
if errorlevel 1 Exit
:: Last if not needed, but just to show how to add options
if "%1"=="/n" Echo Direct Launch
Echo Launching . . .

Start Program.exe
Exit /b
```

And that should do what you want in the console.

- Calling it with no parameters will prompt
- With `/y` will prompt
- With `/n` will not prompt

Mona

Comment: One more thing...
How would I link the VBScript to it :/

Comment: In you could create a temp VBSfile, call it and use the InputBox command to take input (or a simple MSGBOX)